# resize event triggers only when manually resizing browser window on ie8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, caroufredsel

I'm editing some legacy code and we use CarouFredSel plugin here - http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel and so i got myself into this strange problem - in ie8 plugin items initializes in some misaligned position.

When i manually resize the window everything realigns perfectly. But i can't find any solution with javascript.

What i tried so far - $(window).resize(), $(document).resize(), then manually adjusting some elements - html or body .css('width', '99%') and so on. Nothing works yet except manual browser resizing.

I think the solution might be in the source of the plugin, but i got no such force to find it.

Comment: have you tried with $(window).trigger('resize'); ?

Comment: @TomaszRozmus , yes, same story.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or live demo?

Comment: @TomaszRozmus i'm afraid i cannot give you the link, but i pasted beautified library here if it would help http://jsfiddle.net/04uf74bp/

I also have this thought that maybe it is the emulation that might influence the issue - i'm emulating ie8 with ie11 dev tools.

Comment: Okay, it's definitely something in the plugin source, because even in chrome browser when i mess up the dimensions with inline css and then trigger resize() event it does not work, but manually resizing window fixed the problem.

Still have no idea what to look for, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i finally found that this function does exactly what i've needed - carousel.trigger('updateSizes'); (when initialising a plugin you have to assign it to a variable, in my case it's carousel)

it recalculates the dimensions of carousel, strange thing that it does not trigger when i've tried all the previous options!